# Population II star orbits

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-motion, star-clusters, stellar-dynamics

Ok so they are usually found in globular clusters and can consider orbits in a static spherically symmetric gravitational field. The orbits are randomly scattered. Would these be considered to be collisional or collisionless orbits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are pretty collisionless. As a rough estimate, the time to a close encounter within radius $r$ is $\tau \approx 1/(\pi r^2 v \rho)$ where $v$ is the average velocity ($\approx$ 20 km/s) and $\rho$ the average number density ($\approx$ 0.4 per parsec on average, 100-1000 times more in the core). So for <1 AU encounters that gives $\tau\approx 10^{15}$ years, while the timescale is a 1000 times less in the core - $10^{12}$ years, still really long. Still, 100 AU encounters thappen much more often and a lot of weak interactions sum up, so [the cluster relaxes in a few hundred million years anyway](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~george/ay20/Ay20-Lec15x.pdf).

To complicate things slightly, three-body encounters can generate binaries, and "hard" binaries (binding energy bigger than average kinetic energy in the cluster) [tend to become harder when interacting randomly with other star](https://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~vasily/Lectures/SDSG/sdsg_7_clusters.pdf)s ("Heggie’s law").

But actual stellar mergers likely mostly happen right now due to hard binaries evolving into giant stars and dissipating their orbital velocity rather than actual random close encounters.